# Почему компилятор считает String Object`ом?

Tags: java, строки, ооп, объекты, конструктор

```
 public Outcome(String name, int odds) {
    this.name = name;
    this.odds = odds;
}

public Outcome(String name, int odds, int[] bins) {
    super(name, odds);
    this.bins = bins;
}
```

Выходит ошибка при вызове `super(...)`:

> in Object cannot be applied.to (java.lang.String, int)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что вы вызываете конструктор родительского объекта, который в данном случае является Object. Чтобы вызвать перегруженный метод нужно использовать `this(String, int)`.